# Share Ethernet over Airport (Macbook PRO, Mountain Lion) to Windows XP - No DHCP

Tags: macos, wifi, tethering, windows

I'm not able to share network from Ethernet to WiFi (AirPort) on my 10.8.2 (MBP 13", 2012, MacBookPro9,2)

I'm able to create both protected and unprotected networks, and authenticate from Win XP. But then there is no DHCP running, and neither on Static IP Setting I'm not able to share the network. Those two scenarios are described below.

In my situation I cannot test it out with Windows Vista/7, as I don't have any available.

Is there anyone who has tried to solve this issue on Mountain Lion yet?
Console after setting up sharing is below.

**Scenario 1 (DHCP)**

```
# Ethernet
IP  10.0.0.146
GW  10.0.0.138
DNS 8.8.8.8

# AirPort - DHCP
# Some kind of self assigned address

# Win XP
# Connected (no matter if WPA2/WEP security is in place)
# Still in state "Resolving network address" (aka waiting for DHCP)
```

**Scenario 2 (Static IP)**

```
# Ethernet
IP  10.0.0.146
GW  10.0.0.138
DNS 8.8.8.8

# AirPort (Static IP)
IP  10.0.0.150
GW  10.0.0.146
DNS 8.8.8.8

# Windows XP
IP  10.0.0.151
GW  10.0.0.150
DNS 8.8.8.8
```

**Console**

```
10.10.12 15:04:42,393 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]: InternetSharing: com.apple.InternetSharing.broadcast-0 has been started
10.10.12 15:04:42,398 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]: BCAST is ready [en0, mtu=1500, 2 DNS server(s), 0 DNSv6 server(s)]
10.10.12 15:04:42,398 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]: removed addr=fe80::7ed1:c3ff:fe85:2df4 on en1
10.10.12 15:04:42,399 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]: added addr=192.168.2.1 mask=255.255.255.0 on bridge0
10.10.12 15:04:42,400 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]: com.apple.InternetSharing.broadcast-0 started: [DNS subnet=192.168.2/24 on bridge0]
10.10.12 15:04:42,400 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]:   dns[0]: 10.0.0.138
10.10.12 15:04:42,400 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]:   dns[1]: 10.0.0.138
10.10.12 15:04:42,401 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]: com.apple.InternetSharing.broadcast-0 started: [DHCP subnet=192.168.2/24 on bridge0 mtu=1500 <---> en0 mtu=1500] max-mss=1460
10.10.12 15:04:42,401 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]:   dns[0]: 192.168.2.1
10.10.12 15:04:42,402 com.apple.InternetSharing[13724]: started "natpmpd"
10.10.12 15:04:42,000 kernel[0]: bridge_attach_protocol: en1
10.10.12 15:04:42,000 kernel[0]: bridge0: successfully restored 1 suspended link-layer multicast membership(s) (err=0)
10.10.12 15:04:42,411 named[13726]: starting BIND 9.8.3-P1 -c /etc/com.apple.named.proxy.conf -f
10.10.12 15:04:42,411 named[13726]: built with '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/private/etc' '--localstatedir=/private/var' '--enable-atomic=no' '--with-openssl=yes' '--with-gssapi=yes' '--enable-symtable=none' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc' 'CFLAGS=-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -gdwarf-2 ' 'LDFLAGS=-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation' 'CXX=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++' 'CXXFLAGS=-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe '
10.10.12 15:04:42,411 named[13726]: ----------------------------------------------------
10.10.12 15:04:42,411 named[13726]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
10.10.12 15:04:42,412 named[13726]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit 
10.10.12 15:04:42,412 named[13726]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are 
10.10.12 15:04:42,412 named[13726]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
10.10.12 15:04:42,412 named[13726]: ----------------------------------------------------
10.10.12 15:04:42,422 named[13726]: Warning: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones
10.10.12 15:04:42,429 named[13726]: running
10.10.12 15:04:42,433 named[13726]: Warning: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones
10.10.12 15:04:42,446 named[13726]: Warning: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones
10.10.12 15:04:42,702 configd[18]: arp_client_transmit(en1) failed, Device not configured (6)
10.10.12 15:04:42,702 configd[18]: MANUAL en1: arp probe failed, arp_client_transmit(en1) failed, Device not configured (6)
10.10.12 15:04:46,452 mDNSResponderHelper[13723]: do_mDNSInterfaceAdvtIoctl: ioctl call SIOCGIFINFO_IN6 failed - error (22) Invalid argument
10.10.12 15:04:46,453 mDNSResponderHelper[13723]: do_mDNSInterfaceAdvtIoctl: ioctl call SIOCGIFINFO_IN6 failed - error (22) Invalid argument
10.10.12 15:04:46,453 mDNSResponderHelper[13723]: do_mDNSInterfaceAdvtIoctl: ioctl call SIOCGIFINFO_IN6 failed - error (22) Invalid argument
10.10.12 15:04:49,775 bootpd[13727]: server name Marek.local
10.10.12 15:04:49,776 bootpd[13727]: interface en0: ip 10.0.0.148 mask 255.255.255.0
10.10.12 15:04:49,776 bootpd[13727]: interface vnic0: ip 10.211.55.2 mask 255.255.255.0
10.10.12 15:04:49,776 bootpd[13727]: interface vnic1: ip 10.37.129.2 mask 255.255.255.0
10.10.12 15:04:49,776 bootpd[13727]: interface bridge0: ip 192.168.2.1 mask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works here:

The missing detail is found in the last line of the console output above:
bridge0 ip: 192.168.2.1
(a bridge is created when the connection is shared to pass packets between the two network interfaces)

1. create a static IP on the wifi interface:

   > IP: 192.168.4.13
   >   Netmask: 255.255.255.0
   >   NO ROUTER address
2. Share the connection in System Preferences -> sharing
3. At a terminal type > `ifconfig`
   the output should contain a bridge0 section with an inet of 192.168.2.1
4. on the remote host configure the wifi interface with a 192.168.2.13 address and a router (gateway) address of 192.168.2.1
5. The connection should be shared